# Nested triangular loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the following in Java which basically does a nested triangular loop:

```
    int n = 10;
    B bs[] = new B[n];
    // some initial values, bla bla
    double dt = 0.001;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bs[i] = new B();
        bs[i].x = i * 0.5;
        bs[i].v = i * 2.5;
        bs[i].m = i * 5.5;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = **(i+1)**; j < n; j++) {
            double d = bs[i].x - bs[j].x;

            double sqr = d * d + 0.01;
            double dist = Math.sqrt(sqr);
            double mag = dt / (sqr * dist);

            bs[i].v -= d * bs[j].m * mag;
            **bs[j].v += d * bs[i].m * mag;**
        }
    }   

    // printing out the value v
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(bs[i].v);
    }
```

Class B:

```
class B {
    double x, v, m;
}
```

In each iteration, the value at index i and j of the array is updated at the same time thus avoiding to do a complete nested loop. The following gives the same result but it does a complete nested loop (excuse me for the terms i'm using, they may not be correct but i hope it does make sense).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            double d = bs[i].x - bs[j].x;

            double sqr = d * d + 0.01;
            double dist = Math.sqrt(sqr);
            double mag = dt / (sqr * dist);

            bs[i].v -= d * bs[j].m * mag;
        }
    }
```

NOTE:
the only change from the previous code is `int j = 0;` NOT `int j = (i+1);` and removed `bs[j].v += d * bs[i].m * mag;`

I want to do same in Haskell but having difficulty to think about it properly. I have the following code. The array in the Haskell version is represented as a list (xs) which i've initialised to 0.

```
n = 20
xs = replicate n 0

update = foldl' (update') xs [0..(n-1)]
    where
        update' i = update'' i (i+1) []
        update'' i j acc
            | j == n = acc
            | otherwise = new_acc
                where
                    new_acc = result:acc
                    result = ...do something
```

I am going to have very big value for n e.g. 1000, 5000, etc.
A complete nested loop when n = 1000 gives `length [(i,j)|i<-[0..1000],j<-[0..1000]] = 1002001` but a triangular version gives `length [(i,j)|i<-[0..1000],j<-[(i+1)..1000]]
= 500500`. Doing 2 maps in Haskell is easy to get it to do the complete loops but I want the triangular version. I guess this implies keeping the changes to i and j in a list and then update the original list at the end? Any idea would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think it would help if you explained what `update_i` and `update_j` does, and what `result` is, otherwise it is not clear how best write what you wish.

Comment: @HaskellElephant: I removed the 2 methods and put the code that goes in there. I've simplified it a lot by removing unnecessary code. You can replace `dt` by any value, it does not matter. Thanks

Comment: @HaskellElephant: Are you sure that your two loops actually do the same thing? After all, the loop may read values `arr` that have already been updated.

Comment: The two loops you have provided are NOT equivalent making it rather difficult to analyse what you are trying to do. Check out the [C code snippet](http://codepad.org/8txeuFRk). I know your code is in Java but Java is not an option at codepad.

Comment: @HaskellElephant,Anupam: you were right, the code did not give equivalent results. My fault. I was just trying to simplify the code I have, but now the code is more complete and if you check, both loops give the same result EXCEPT the first one is a 'triangular' loop while the second is a full nested loop.

Comment: I think there is a good answer cooking in my brain for this. Looping over each item in the list is as simple as recursing and matching on `(x:xs)`. Then The nested loop is as simple as recursing again with only `xs`, or something like that. I'll give it more time to bake and see if something good comes out.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i hope you come out with something.

Comment: Rotsor expressed basically what I was thinking. The weird thing is that your specific example relies heavily on mutable state. It updates both cells during *each* inner iteration. What is this algorithm doing? Looks like a physics simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a straightforward translation using unboxed mutable vectors from the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package. Code is somewhat ugly, but should be very fast:

```
module Main
    where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

numElts :: Int
numElts = 10

dt :: Double
dt = 0.001

loop :: Int -> M.IOVector Double -> M.IOVector Double 
        -> M.IOVector Double -> IO ()
loop n x v m = go 0
  where
    doWork i j = do xI <- M.read x i
                    xJ <- M.read x j
                    vI <- M.read v i
                    vJ <- M.read v j
                    mI <- M.read m i
                    mJ <- M.read m j

                    let d = xI - xJ
                    let sqr = d * d + 0.01
                    let dist = sqrt sqr
                    let mag = dt / (sqr * dist)

                    M.write v i (vI - d * mJ * mag)
                    M.write v j (vJ + d * mI * mag)

    go i | i < n     = do go' (i+1)
                          go  (i+1)
         | otherwise = return ()
      where
        go' j | j < n     = do doWork i j
                               go' (j + 1)
              | otherwise = return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do x <- generateVector 0.5
          v <- generateVector 2.5
          m <- generateVector 5.5
          loop numElts x v m
          v' <- U.unsafeFreeze v
          U.forM_ v' print

    where
      generateVector :: Double -> IO (M.IOVector Double)
      generateVector d = do v <- M.new numElts
                            generateVector' numElts d v
                            return v

      generateVector' :: Int -> Double -> M.IOVector Double -> IO ()
      generateVector' n d v = go 0
        where
          go i | i < n = do M.unsafeWrite v i (fromIntegral i * d)
                            go (i+1)
               | otherwise = return ()
```

**Update**: Regarding the "very fast" claim: I [benchmarked my solution](https://gist.github.com/1039262) against the pure one provided by Federico and got the following results (for `n` = 1000):

```
benchmarking pureSolution
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 334.5483 s
mean: 2.949640 s, lb 2.867693 s, ub 3.005429 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 421.1978 ms, lb 343.8233 ms, ub 539.4906 ms, ci 0.950
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4.0%)
  3 (3.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 5.997%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers

benchmarking pureVectorSolution
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 280.4593 s
mean: 2.747359 s, lb 2.709507 s, ub 2.803392 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 237.7489 ms, lb 179.3110 ms, ub 311.8813 ms, ci 0.950
found 13 outliers among 100 samples (13.0%)
  7 (7.0%) high mild
  6 (6.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 2.998%
variance is slightly inflated by outliers

benchmarking imperativeSolution
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 5.905104 s
mean: 58.59154 ms, lb 56.79405 ms, ub 60.60033 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 11.70101 ms, lb 9.120100 ms, ub NaN s, ci 0.950
```

So the imperative solution is **approx. 50 times faster** than the functional one (the difference is even more dramatic for smaller `n`, when everything fits in cache). I tried to make Federico's solution work with unboxed vectors, but apparently it relies on laziness in a crucial way, which makes the unboxed version loop forever. The "pure vector" version uses boxed vectors.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. The mutable unboxed vector module is new to me. How do i actually print/get back the result in the main function? I mean the updated vector.

Comment: I will get this to work with my existing code and see how it goes. But I would like to see how this can be implemented using immutable array or just list in haskell. That would definitely require accumulating the changes and then finally applying it to the initial array/list.

Comment: I'm not sure that a purely functional solution can be as fast as an imperative one in this case. Destructive update and constant-time indexing are central to your algorithm.

Comment: @Mikhail: Does it really make sense to unsafeThaw there? Is there no sensible way of constructing a mutable vector except constructing an immutable one and unsafely thawing it?

Comment: @Peaker I couldn't find a version of `generate` that works for mutable vectors, and I didn't want to write my own.

Comment: @Peaker Removed calls to `unsafeThaw`.

Comment: @Mikhail, I don't see how destructive updates with fast indexing are fundamental here. First, the indices are not arbitrarily calculated, but are consecutively iterated over. Second, the loop body never reads bs[i].v. These two facts hint at the possibility of an efficient list-based solution.

Comment: @Rotsor I'd be happy to be wrong. Can you show me a purely functional solution (perhaps with immutable vectors) that is as fast as mine (for large inputs)?

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail, for the detailed comparison of the answers. If i want to keep my code pure, i will stick to Frederico's version otherwise your version gives the best perf.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this solves your problem because I didn't grasp it completely yet, but the triangular loop itself is very easy to do in Haskell:

```
triangularLoop :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
triangularLoop f xs = do
    (x1 : t) <- tails xs
    x2 <- t
    return $ f x1 x2
```

Or, written without the monadic syntax,

```
triangularLoop f = concat . map singlePass . tails
    where
        singlePass [] = []
        singlePass (h:t) = map (f h) t
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical, idiomatic  way of writing nested loops in Haskell is using list comprehensions.

Here is how I would translate your code:

```
import Data.Array

import Data.List (tails)

data Body = Body {x::Double,v::Double,m::Double}
            deriving Show

n::Int
n = 9

dt::Double
dt = 0.001

bs_0 :: Array Int Body
bs_0 = array (0,n) [(i,Body {x = i'*0.5,v = i'*2.5,m = i'*5.5}) | 
                    i <- [0..n], let i' = fromIntegral i]

bs :: Array Int Body
bs = accum (\b dv -> b {v = v b + dv}) bs_0 dvs
     where 
       dvs :: [(Int,Double)]
       dvs = concat [[(i,dv_i),(j,dv_j)] | (i:is) <- tails [0..n], 
                                            j <- is,
                                            let d = x(bs!i) - x(bs!j)
                                                sqr =  d * d + 0.01
                                                dist = sqrt sqr
                                                mag = dt / (sqr * dist)
                                                dv_i = -d * m(bs!j) * mag
                                                dv_j =  d * m(bs!i) * mag]

main :: IO()
main = mapM_ print (assocs bs)
```

Comment: FYI, I [benchmarked your code](https://gist.github.com/1039262). The imperative solution is much faster; I couldn't get your code to work with unboxed vectors, however.